Ubuntu won't boot from SSD, will from USB stick
I know this is a vague title but I don't know what to post here.
Ubuntu won't boot from the SSD.  I get a lot of messages on the terminal, not always the same.  One of them is:
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-ssh.soc... SSSD SSH Service responder socket

Another is:
Bluetooth hci0: malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
Bluetooth hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported

I can get to the GRUB menu but the memtest gives me a "bad shim signature" error.
I can boot from a USB stick and I have backups.  Should I just reinstall?  fsck of my SSD shows no errors and I can see the files.  Is there a log I should look at or post here?
I apologize for not being more specific.
EDIT: I can boot to a recovery prompt and there's four files in /var/crash.  journalctl -b -1 -e shows a lot of text that I don't know how to interpret.
EDIT2: Cross-posted to https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1gl7nee/ubuntu_2404_wont_boot_prints_terminal_messages/

What system is there in the SSD? Which version (22.04 LTS or 24.04 LTS or some other version)? Is the system installed, in that case how? Has the system in the SSD worked before? In order to run memtest, turn off secure boot and try again.

SSD has Ubuntu 24.04.1 on it and it worked until this morning.  I don't know how to turn secure boot off but I will look it up.  Thanks.

Can you remember what you did with Ubuntu before it stopped working? You can check / repair the file system of the SSD system when booted from the USB drive using e2fsck.  See details at this link and this link.

Last thing I do at night is backup (DejaDup I think),  memtest just passed, I will try the e2fsck now...

e2fsck optimized an extent tree, but found no errors.  Ubuntu on /dev/sda2 still doesn't boot (messages on a terminal screen, then no response.)  Is it time to reinstall Ubuntu from my USB stick and then restore my backup of /home/xxx ?

Yes, I think it is a good idea, probably the fastest way to restore your system. It is probably possible to repair the system, but it might take a long time to find the problem ...
